# Removing a specific aspect of a TI-84 8xk app

Tags: assembly

I really like this program, [Symbolic](http://www.detachedsolutions.com/symbolic/), but in my school's calculus course we are not allowed to use programs that can differentiate/integrate. Thus, I want to remove the differentiation function from this app.

The download includes all the ASM files and a ZWS which seem to be used to compile the application. While I don't know much about Assembly, is it possible to simply recompile this application, leaving out the differentiation function's ASM? If so, how?